# WinRT: How to email a message to a specific person?

Tags: windows-runtime, sharing

I'm trying to port a [conference app sample](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/update-on-mvvmcross-sqlbits-conference.html) to WinRT at present.

In this app there are some feature where users can email specific people - e.g. on certain screens they can click buttons to send an email to the conference organisers, to one of the speakers, or to me - the app developer.

I've looked through [the WinRT documents on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx) and the only contract I can find which might be related to email is [sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758315.aspx) - and this doesn't seem to allow you to specify who you are sharing too.

Is there some simple "send email to" method available in WinRT? e.g. something like [EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) in WP7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("mailto:" + emailAddress, UriKind.Absolute);
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

It looks weird, but it works.

This allows you to set the email address and the subject, but not a full HTML body.

Using the share contract, you can set the subject and the body, but - indeed - not the address. This makes sense, as after all you don't know what app your content will be shared with. It may not be an email app at all, but e.g. a blog writer.

Comment: Good suggestion! Will try tomorrow. Thanks +1

Comment: This solution does not work for me after I'd installed Chrome. Launcher opens the link in the Chrome, not in the default mail client.